# Debugging without a.out in VSC

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code

I wanted to debug my code in Visual Studio Code. However, i am missing `a.out`. I think i might've deleted it. How do i get it back? Is there any way to debug without it? Can i write it myself?

The only thing i came up with is copy paste the code to whole different folder, make new makefile and such. That is tedious and i think there might be easier, out of my reach, solutions.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

This is the `launch.js` file, i have tried substituting the `a.out` with something like `Makefile` as it made some sense(well that i think of it, i linked the code, nothing in executable manner) but did not work. I even tried the executable object `obj`(when running `./obj`) but nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: `a.out` is the default name for the build target on some platforms.  To get it back, rebuild your project.

Comment: Do you mean to just `make`? Because i used that and it still could not find it.

Comment: Wait, i just did something. In the `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out"` i replaced `a.out` with the, in my specific case `vector` which i use for `./vector` and it worked. I think i might have typed in wrong name before when first trying because i was switching the projects in order to see any difference. Although still no `a.out` when using makefile, did the `vector` by any chance replaced it?

Answer (score 1):

`a.out` is the default file name for the compiled program. It's used if you don't give a name for the output file when you run the compiler. The name of the output file is typically given with the `-o` option when running the compiler on the command line.

It sounds like you have changed some settings now so that the compiled program is now called "vector" instead of "a.out". So just change the debugger settings too, to use "vector" instead "a.out".

Comment: Yep, it seems like it is like that. Thanks.